# Can I use same branch to revert changes which is merged to master

Tags: git, git-merge

I have Branch 'A' Merged into Master, now i have to revert my changes done in branch 'A',
So can i take the **same** branch 'A' and revert code and push and add MR to master ?

I want to do it manually..

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can. do the changes and open a Pull Request/Merge Request. 
Before you're doing changes make sure to switch to the 'A' branch using `git switch A` or `git checkout A`

Comment: Branch 'A' is very old, if i use same branch that will bring lot of conflict issues. that why i have planned to use new branch add changes..

Comment: In that case better to use a new branch